# OpenFeign + Hystrix - Different timeout for different clients

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have Hystrix working with Feign in my Spring Boot Application.

I have set the default timeout for Hystrix to 10000ms with:

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```

The problem is I have this one client, lets call it `HeavyClient`, that is a heavy call that sometimes takes more time and causes the circuit break.
**I would like to increase the timeout cap in Hystrix for this one guy only. Is it possible?**

I have tried with Feign properties like:

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      HeavyClient:
        connectTimeout: 30000
        readTimeout: 30000
```

But this doesn't work. I guess Hystrix does not check Feign properties.

I'm using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could do this if you set the hystrix timeout at the dependency (heavy client ) level. you could identify the heavy client by the hystrix command key.

Comment: Hystrix.command.heavyclient.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds = 40000 . Here heavyclient is ur command key.

Comment: Hi @IndraneelBende, I have tried that, using the same ID I give to my `@FeignClient` and it doesnt work. It still uses the `default` timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweeking around and search more deeply I have found on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1864) that default naming for Hystrix commands are something ugly like `InterfaceName#methodNameSignature()`.

So, for instance, given the following `@FeignClient`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "heavyClient", url = "${heavyclient.url}")
public interface HeavyClient {
    
    @RequestMapping("/process/{operation}")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> process(@PathVariable("operation") String operation);
    
}
```

It would be configured as:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
    HeavyClient#process(String):
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

Unfortunelly, this did not work for me... Not sure why... =s
So to solve it, I registered a bean of type `SetterFactory` that would create the command keys given the `@FeignClient` name:

```
    @Bean
    public SetterFactory setterFactory() {
        return (target, method) -> HystrixCommand.Setter
                .withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey(target.name()))
                .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(target.name()));
    }
```

And then I can use the configuration simply like:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    heavyClient:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

Answer (score 0):

`CircuitBreakerNameResolver` to naming circuit as HystrixCommandKey, there is a default implementation `DefaultCircuitBreakerNameResolver`, which output key pattern is `HardCodedTarget#methodName(ParamClass)`, so you can customize `CircuitBreakerNameResolver` instead of `DefaultCircuitBreakerNameResolver`.